# 「SocialConnector」が起動しない

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d

「SocialConnector」が起動しない

Unityで開発を行っております。

iPadにて画面スクリーンショットを共有したく「SocialConnector」を使用しているのですが
なにも起動せず、動作していない状況であります。

流れとして
1.スクリーンショットを作成
2.保存ボタン押下で「SocialConnector」呼び出し
としております。
他にXcode上で「SocialConnector.mm」のComplie Flagsの箇所に「-fno-objc-arc」を記入しております。

コードは

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public class FwShareController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // 画像を共有
    public void share( string a_path )
    {
        SocialConnector.SocialConnector.Share( "photography", "http://www.hoge.co.jp/", a_path );
    }
}
```

になります。

出力されたエラーは

```
2023-05-16 21:58:53.768893+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=66, _LSFunction=_LSServer_GetServerStoreForConnectionWithCompletionHandler}
2023-05-16 21:58:53.769889+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2023-05-16 21:58:53.769989+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=66, _LSFunction=_LSServer_GetServerStoreForConnectionWithCompletionHandler}
2023-05-16 21:58:54.542436+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [default] LaunchServices: store (null) or url (null) was nil: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=66, _LSFunction=_LSServer_GetServerStoreForConnectionWithCompletionHandler}
2023-05-16 21:58:54.542522+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [default] Attempt to map database failed: permission was denied. This attempt will not be retried.
2023-05-16 21:58:54.542702+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7606510] [db] Failed to initialize client context with error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "process may not map database" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=process may not map database, _LSLine=66, _LSFunction=_LSServer_GetServerStoreForConnectionWithCompletionHandler}
2023-05-16 21:58:54.753167+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28ba851d0 h=-&- v=--& _UIActivityContentNavigationBar:0x110cf9eb0.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UILayoutContainerView:0x110cf9ae0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28ba877f0 h=-&- v=--& _UIActivityContentNavigationBar:0x110cf9eb0.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52030 V:[_UIActivityContentNavigationBar:0x110cf9eb0]-(0)-[UIFocusContainerGuide:0x28236b390'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb51900 UIFocusContainerGuide:0x28236b390'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide'.bottom == UILayoutContainerView:0x110cf9ae0.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb506e0 V:|-(0)-[UILayoutContainerView:0x110cf9ae0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x110cf5500 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb50690 UILayoutContainerView:0x110cf9ae0.bottom == UIView:0x110cf5500.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb51450 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x110cf5500.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52030 V:[_UIActivityContentNavigationBar:0x110cf9eb0]-(0)-[UIFocusContainerGuide:0x28236b390'UINavigationControllerContentFocusContainerGuide']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2023-05-16 21:58:54.984824+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb55220 H:|-(0)-[_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x145e5ebd0]   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb54fa0 _UIActivityContentTitleView:0x145e5ebd0.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb54dc0 LPLinkView:0x16351f800.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x2825a5b20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb54a00 LPLinkView:0x16351f800.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x2825a5b20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb56350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570.width == 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb54e60 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(29)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2825a5b20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x145e5ebd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb548c0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x2825a5b20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIActivityContentTitleView:0x145e5ebd0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb54a00 LPLinkView:0x16351f800.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x2825a5b20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2023-05-16 21:58:54.987060+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb53020 UILayoutGuide:0x282569ea0'BackButtonGuide(0x110cfa8b0)'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x28256e140'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52cb0 H:[UILayoutGuide:0x282569ea0'BackButtonGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28256bf00'LeadingBarGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52da0 H:[UILayoutGuide:0x28256bf00'LeadingBarGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28256bc60'TitleViewGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52440 UILayoutGuide:0x28256bc60'TitleViewGuide(0x110cfa8b0)'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52d00 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28256e140'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb56350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570.width == 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb525d0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(16)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52cb0 H:[UILayoutGuide:0x282569ea0'BackButtonGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x28256bf00'LeadingBarGuide(0x110cfa8b0)']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2023-05-16 21:58:54.990213+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52440 UILayoutGuide:0x28256bc60'TitleViewGuide(0x110cfa8b0)'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52490 UILayoutGuide:0x28256bc60'TitleViewGuide(0x110cfa8b0)'.leading >= UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb56350 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570.width == 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52580 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(16)-[UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb525d0 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(16)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x110cfa570 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28bb52440 UILayoutGuide:0x28256bc60'TitleViewGuide(0x110cfa8b0)'.trailing <= UILayoutGuide:0x282563100'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2023-05-16 21:58:55.036905+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [UICollectionLayout] <_UIActivityCollectionViewCompositionalLayout 0x110cf56b0> ran into an error when computing the layout for section at index 0 in container <_UICollectionLayoutContainer: 0x28c453780 contentSize={-7, 0}; contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}}>. UICollectionView behavior with this layout is undefined. Break on UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutAlertForInvalidLayout to catch this in the debugger.
Error: NSCollectionLayoutItem created with invalid combination of spacing and size specified. This group cannot fit even a single item. Inspect the spacing and size of the items in this group and ensure that they fit into the group when its effective size is {42.666666666666657, 128}.
Group: <NSCollectionLayoutGroup size={.absolute(42.6667), .estimated(128)};
     edgeSpacing=<leading=.fixed(0); top=.fixed(0); trailing=.fixed(0); bottom=.fixed(0)>;
     contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}>
     group: subitems=
         <NSCollectionLayoutItem size={.absolute(78), .estimated(128)};
         edgeSpacing=<leading=.fixed(0); top=.fixed(0); trailing=.fixed(0); bottom=.fixed(0)>;
         contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}>
     interItemSpacing=.fixed(-95.66666666666667);
     layoutDirection=.horizontal>
2023-05-16 21:58:55.037265+0900 HogeHoge[49283:7605584] [UICollectionLayout] <_UIActivityCollectionViewCompositionalLayout 0x110cf56b0> ran into an error when computing the layout for section at index 1 in container <_UICollectionLayoutContainer: 0x28c453900 contentSize={-7, 0}; contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}}>. UICollectionView behavior with this layout is undefined. Break on UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutAlertForInvalidLayout to catch this in the debugger.
Error: NSCollectionLayoutItem created with invalid combination of spacing and size specified. This group cannot fit even a single item. Inspect the spacing and size of the items in this group and ensure that they fit into the group when its effective size is {43.333333333333343, 128}.
Group: <NSCollectionLayoutGroup size={.absolute(43.3333), .estimated(128)};
     edgeSpacing=<leading=.fixed(0); top=.fixed(0); trailing=.fixed(0); bottom=.fixed(0)>;
     contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}>
     group: subitems=
         <NSCollectionLayoutItem size={.absolute(78), .estimated(128)};
         edgeSpacing=<leading=.fixed(0); top=.fixed(0); trailing=.fixed(0); bottom=.fixed(0)>;
         contentInsets={0, 0, 0, 0}>
     interItemSpacing=.fixed(-95.33333333333333);
     layoutDirection=.horizontal>
```

になります。

他に必要な事などありますでしょうか。

環境
Unity　2020.3.1f1
Social Connector v0.5.0

になります。